# Set different views in one Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I've created a button, if I click it the following will start:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Crunch();
    tts.speak("Kurze Pause", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);     
    Unterarm();
            SitUp();

}
```

By calling Crunch(), I want to `setContentView(R.layout.1)`, when it is finished I want to change the contentView to another layout, by calling Unterarm(). Then to another one by calling SitUp().

How can I handle it in the best way? I've created all of the layouts and methods, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because it **will execute all methods without any delay between them** so you will get the feeling that only the last one is working and if the last one is restoring the initial state, you'll feel like nothing is happening.

I suggest you wrap the method inside an `asyncTask` and set some delay between the method calls. It should be straight forward enough.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. But how can I handle it? I read the Android-Dev-Page, but i can't find the right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use animations, this is from the offical documentation

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

hope it helps :)

Comment: But i only want to click one time on the button, then it should start the different methods one by one.